# OpenOCD Eclipse STM32VL problem

Tags: eclipse, openocd

I am working through setting up eclipse with openOCD to program a STM32VL discovery board using the following guide https://www.carminenoviello.com/2014/12/28/setting-gcceclipse-toolchain-stm32nucleo-part-1/ .

I have got all the way to the end but am stuck on trying to program it with the OpenOCD but I keep getting the following error:

`GNU MCU Eclipse 32-bits Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00254-g2ec04e4e (2017-11-10-11:53)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 1000 kHz, using 950 kHz
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'`

I am aware after alot of research there is bug with openOCD with USB3.0 but my device only has 3.0 ports...

I have using OpenOCD 0.10.0 
My External tools configuration in eclipse is setup as:
C:\STM32ToolChain\openocd\bin\openocd.exe
C:\STM32ToolChain\openocd\scripts\
-f board\stm32vldiscovery.cfg

With my above .cfd setup as

```
#This is an STM32VL discovery board with a single STM32F100RB chip.
#http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/250863.jsp
source [find interface/stlink-v1.cfg]
transport select hla_swd
set WORKAREASIZE 0x2000
source [find target/stm32f1x.cfg]
reset_config srst_only`
```

Has anyone else had any similar problems?

Comment: Ultimately you should be able to get openocd to work, but you might want to briefly try either the texane/stlink tool or ST's official one (since you seem to be on Windows anyway) as a cross check on the hardware situation.  Also you have the required jumpers installed, right?   You might also try while holding down the target reset button.

Comment: I can connect to the board with ST-link if that's what you're enquiring? Is there any way to use openOCD in some kind seperate application way away from eclipse, to check it can connect/recognise it? (to try and isolate the problem)
I have two jumpers on them as the board is given, i.e. pins are connected for jumpers beside designators 1 and CH3 but the two jumpers beside SWD are empty (not connected)

Comment: ST has software for windows for programming the board, you should download and try it to verify the hardware is correctly configured and not damaged.  And yes, of course you can run openocd from the command line, but it's not clear that would give a different result.

Comment: ST-link can connect and flash the board so I believe the hardware is fine.

Comment: Apologies St-link Utility

Comment: Also which exact board do you have?  I believe the Discovery for the STM32F100 used the ancient, buggy v1 interface, while the more recent ones use the v2 (or for nucleos what openocd calls v2-1) interface.

Comment: It is the v1 as when I connect over ST-link utility it comes up as this.